# AWS EC2インスタンスに ElasticIP の関連付ける必要性はあるか

Tags: aws

０から順を辿ってAWS VPC EC2の設定をしているんですが、ここでElasticIPの設定部分が書いてありません。画像を見る限りあきらかにElasticIPが設定されているので、関連付ければよいのでしょうか？

関連付ける際、インスタンスかネットワークインターフェイス
どちらに関連付ければよいのでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/hiroshik1985/items/f078a6a017d092a541cf

> IPの確認
>
> [Instances]のリストの中から、今起動したEC2インスタンスを選択すると、下側に[Description]が表示される。その中の項目のPublic
> IP/Elastic IPがグローバルIPとなる。（画像赤塗りつぶし部分）
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問内容に即したタイトルを付けてください。「AWS ELBについて」「AWS ELBについて教えて下さい」「AWS ELBの簡単な質問」等の表現になるのは質問内容がはっきりしていないからと判断しました。そもそもこれらのタイトルで質問者さんは内容を区別できるのですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 画像を見る限りあきらかにElasticIPが設定されているので、関連付ければよいのでしょうか？

これは、必要であれば Elastic IP を関連付ける感じです。
インスタンスをリスタートする度に毎回 Public IP が変わってしまうのは困るという場合は Elastic IP を関連付けます。変わってもいい場合は 特に必要ありません。

> 関連付ける際、インスタンスかネットワークインターフェイス
>   どちらに関連付ければよいのでしょうか？

インスタンスのネットワークインターフェースが1つのようですので何方でも大丈夫です。
インスタンスに関連付けると eth0 にElastic IPが関連付けられます。

二つ目以降のインターフェースに割り当てる場合はネットワークインターフェースに割り当てる必要があります。